# Como alterar a visualização apresentada no Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Quero alterar dessa visualização:

[image: Errado]

Para esta visualização que preciso:

[image: Visualização "certa"]

Como altero tal visualização no eclipse?

Comment: Como é "dividido normal"?

Comment: Vou editar e colocar como normalmente fica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para apresentar o jeito "certo", basta que você altere a visualização que deseja utilizar. Tanto para as perspectivas Java EE, quanto Java, existem diversas visualizações, observe que no jeito "errado" é apresentado **Navigator**, enquanto na "certa", **Project Explorer**.

Para incluir uma nova visualização, vá em `Window -> Show View`. No seu caso, escolha `Project Explorer`, como abaixo:

[image: Eclipse Show View]

Depois de selecionado, serão exibidas as duas, nas *tabs* será apresentado assim:

[image: Eclipse Tabs View]

Na visualização de `Project Explorer` temos algo assim:

[image: Eclipse Project ExplorerView]

E na de `Navigator`, algo como isto:

[image: Eclipse Navigator View]

Comment: Meu deus kkkk Me senti uma tia que nao sabe mexer no computador